# Most Effective way to display comments for a post

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

Trying to find the best way to display posts from a database with all of their comments. I know there has to be a better way but I can't come up with one.

In my controller, I am sending to a view the following:

```
$posts = Post::all();

$comments = Comment::all();

return view('layouts.main',compact('posts,comments'));
```

In my view I am displaying each post with all of its comments below.

```
@foreach($posts as $post)

    {{ $post->content }}

    @foreach($comments as $comment)

        @if($comment->post->id == $post->id)
            {{ $comment->content }}
        @endif

    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the comments relationship set up in your posts model?

```
$posts = Post::with('comments')->all();

return view('layouts.main',compact('posts'));
```

And then:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)

    {{ $post->content }}

    @foreach($post->comments as $comment)
            {{ $comment->content }}
    @endforeach

@endforeach
```